# Azure Training Kit Merry-go-round

Tags: azure, training-data

I signed up for Azure 30 day trial but found the on site training videos completely lacking in usefulness.

I contacted support and they sent me a new link for the Azure Training Kit.

The installation seemed to execute without any errors, but left me at a web site with a button to sign up for Azure again.

Any attempt to sign up again fails because I have already signed up.

Does anybody know how I can actually get to the start of the Training Kit and not just a web site telling me just how great it is and what I will find in it?

Comment: I am the PM of the Windows Azure Training Kit, would it be useful to have a block of text on the web site or open the location in File Explorer so you can instantly browse the resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Windows Azure Training Kit](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resources-training-kit/) is usually installed on your computer in **`C:\WATK`** folder. You will see **`HOL`** folder in there which contains lots of hands on labs to get started. I would recommend starting from there or you could look at presentations to get familiar with various aspects of Windows Azure.

Comment: How hard would it have been for Microsoft team to put that prominently on the Azure free trial page? As it is, my "free" trial is half over already.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad my Azure trial expired, but I'll try to check out what's there.